# Probability of a specific boy and a specific girl sitting next to each other

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are $5$ boys and $4$ girls in a class. The boys and girls are seated at a movie theater in a boy-girl fashion. What is the probability that a specific boy, Andrew, is seated next to a specific girl, Jenna?

One possible solution is described [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Videos/external.php?video_id=89); however, this videos suggests that there is an easier way of solving the problem. Can someone please help me find it?

Edit:
The solution turned out to be in a later video, which can be found [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Videos/external.php?video_id=113)

Comment: Consider that there are $5$ boys in the class...

Comment: If you change it in one class no one will notice, change it in 3 and you can be like "oh wow, coincidence!", any more than that and it's stalking, only works until you change classes else again it is stalking. This works for classes of size up to 35. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are going to calculate the probability that the boy sits next to the (already seated) girl. We know that there are two out of the five places where the boy can sit to sit next to the girl. Thus, the probability that the boy and the girl sit next to each other is $\frac 25$.

Answer (score 1):

Add one anonymous girl and make it a circle with boy-girl setting. Andrew has $2$ places next to him for girls and there are $5$ girls. The probability that Jenna is one of these $2$ is $\frac{2}{5}$.